# tsql scope isolation

Tags: sql, t-sql, scope

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN
  DECLARE @d int;
END
BEGIN
  DECLARE @d int;
END

END
```

Doesn't parse with error 134. How can I get scope isolation ? BEGIN...END doesn't provide it.
Looking for the equivalent of {} in C or C++.
Error Msg details: Msg 134, Level 15, State 1.

Comment: Why not declare it outside the blocks and make the value assignment(s) inside the blocks?

Comment: There is no scope isolation in SQL Server. A variable exists for the entire duration of the batch it was declared in. SQL isn't a programming language, and it certainly isn't an Object Orientated Language; it's a Query Language.

Comment: [How can an object-oriented programmer get his/her head around database-driven programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481582/how-can-an-object-oriented-programmer-get-his-her-head-around-database-driven-pr). Not an answer, but a good read.

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . Declare all parameters that you are going to use at the beginning of the procedure.  That will isolate you from the arcane scoping rules of T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by everyone in the comments: the scope of the variable lasts from the point it was declared till the end of the stored procedure. It cannot be isolated. You can declare it in the beginning of the procedure and set the values differently however and whenever required.

However, if you really want to do that, you can use dynamic sql as a workaround ( although it is not recommended ):

```
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE myproc
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN
  exec sp_executesql N'DECLARE @d int; set  @d = 50;select @d';
END
BEGIN
  exec sp_executesql N'DECLARE @d int; set  @d = 500;select @d';
END

END;
```

When you execute the above procedure, you will get the 50 and 500 as output.